# Android unzip archive that contains symlink

Tags: android, zip, symlink

I've been working on something that requires me to extract files from a zip archive on an Android system that contains symlinks.

When I try to create an archive using `zip --symlinks` command on the Android filesystem, the symlinks are stored correctly.
When I try to extract the files on a Linux system, `ls` shows that the symlink links point to the correct place (e.g `symlink -> /storage/emulated/legacy`).
However, when I use unzip in the adb shell, the extracted symlink don't point to the desired location.

How can I extract the symlinks and make them point to the location they pointed before they were archived? Is it even possible?